# What OEIS sequence is this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, oeis

I've come up with an idea of an integer sequence. It can be formulated (perhaps a bit loosely) as follows:  **For *n* points *N(n)* is the number of configurations where each point either lies on some circle or is a center of some circle. Each point lying on a circle can belong to only 1 circle and each center point can be the center of only 1 circle.**

Then *N(1) = 2  N(2) = 5 N(3) = 10  N(4) = 20
N(5) = 36*
(I double checked N(5) but there is no guarantee that it is the right number)

Depending on how *N(0)* is defined  (*N(0)=0 or N(0)=1*)  this sequence very well can be **[A000712](http://oeis.org/A000712)**. However it appears that my description is new, so it easily can be another sequence.

[**all configurations for N(1), N(2), N(3) are shown here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdrBi.png)

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+5%2C+10%2C+20%2C+36&sort=&language=english&go=Search

Comment: Number of configurations of what, exactly? of points? of circles?

Comment: configurations of points.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your construction, it's a little too-loosely defined. Can you be more precise?

Comment: Frankly I think it is more or less intuitively clear if you look at the examples: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdrBi.png  Another problem that arises from this construction is to count the number of circles used in all the configurations for each n. This sequence goes like 2,8,22,54...  and it is not in the OEIS. I do not in any way insist that it should be added though.

Comment: @Amir Sagiv.  I reformulated it in this way:   For n points N(n) is the number of configurations where each point either lies on some circle or is a center of some circle. Each point lying on a circle can belong to only 1 circle and each center point can be the center of only 1 circle.

Comment: It should be possible to understand a question here from what's written here, without needing to go off to stack.imgur

Comment: I would add something along the line of "given an infinite collection of unlabelled disjoint circles...". I think what induces confusion is we feel like we can pick circles later, which is another question (for instance, for three points, either they are aligned and they can be put on two circles, or they are not so they can be put on just one circle, so I would have thought N(3) is at most 2).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your sequence is the same as the linked OEIS sequence. This is the

> Number of partitions of $n$ into parts of two kinds.

In your case, the two kinds are circles for which the centre is occupied and circles for which the centre is not occupied. See the "example" section in the OEIS entry where you can match with your worked out example.